# Can Apache be gracefully restarted without clearing the mod_cache_socache cache?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, http, cache

I recently enabled `mod_cache_socache` on Apache and created a large memory cache

Unfortunately it seems impossible to cache anything for longer than a day due to logrotate doing a graceful restart of Apache at midnight, which seems to flush the cache

I was hoping that the cache would be "owned" by the Apache master process, which isn't restarted when a graceful restart is done, restarting all the child processes.  But it appears that the cache is cleared anyway.

Doing further testing, manually killing child processes one at a time and letting Apache restart them, I can get away with it to a certain extent without the cache clearing, but one of the child processes always seems to be "load bearing", and killing it results in all other child processes restarting & the cache clearing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution to persist mod_cache_socache as by nature it's designed to be cleared on restart and not persist. However, one alternative you can consider is using `mod_cache_disk` for caching in Apache. While it stores cached data on the disk, modern operating systems automatically cache frequently accessed files in memory. This means:

1. **Persistence**: Your cache remains intact even after the server restarts.
2. **Speed**: Due to OS file caching, frequently accessed cache files are served directly from the system's RAM.

Alternatively, you could use a RAM disk for the cache storage location if you don't want this on disk. This way, it will be cleared on a complete server restart.

Comment: I already have all of /var/www cached in RAM using the vmtouch utility (it runs at bootup and then once a day to catch new files), so I'm not sure if an additional disk cache is going to do much.  Given that /var/www is already perma-cached in RAM, I'm not sure mod_cache is even of much benefit, but I have a lot of unused RAM on this server and I'm just trying to do something with it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather then reload apache daily, why not change the way logging works - Instead of logging directly to disk, log through Syslog, or use piped logs.

Per the section "Piped Logs" at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html "One important use of piped logs is to allow log rotation without having to restart the server. The Apache HTTP Server includes a simple program called rotatelogs for this purpose. For example, to rotate the logs every 24 hours, you can use:

```
  CustomLog "|/usr/local/apache/bin/rotatelogs /var/log/access_log 86400" common
```

"

Comment: That's a possibility.  Any known caveats / consequences of allowing Apache child processes to run for days/weeks without restarting?  One concern that occurs to me would be my SSL certificates, I'd need to make sure the server does restart at some point in the 30 days between certificate renewal and old certificate expiration, but I could do a post-renewal hook in certbot, or maybe just do a precautionary restart every two weeks.

Comment: Piped logging and logging to syslog are two different things, right?  The page you linked mentions both but only contains a config example for piped logging.  Researching further, I found a mod_syslog document but it's for 2.5 and doesn't seem to exist in 2.4.

Comment: I believe that syslog logging generally uses piping through the "logger" program.  I had not thought about cert rollover - I guess this is an edge case where buying a multi-year positiveSSL cert or similar might not be a waste of money.

Comment: Ive not love looked into mod_cache in any depth before - but I wonder if you could bypass the problem altogether by using the memcached or redis backend per the section "Shared Object Cache Providers" at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/socache.html

Comment: after doing some testing seems like memcache and redis are both viable options, thanks for the suggestion